How to render component instance with h() function in Vuejs?
I have a Vuejs component that looks like this:
<template>
  <button @click="generateItem()">Add item</button>
  <div class="container"></div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { h } from 'vue'
  import MyItem from '@/components/MyItem.vue'

  function generateItem(){
    return h(MyItem)
  }
</script>

I'm trying to use an h() function to render an instance of MyItem inside div.container when running generateItem(). But after reading the official Vuejs docs on the h() function I don't get how to make this happen. Thoughts on how to get this done?

The function might work already, but you need to give it a place to insert the generated vNode. Maybe try with a v-if somewhere in your template to then insert the new component. Also, do you even need Render functions here? Can't you insert the component directly?

@kissu how would I go about inserting the vNode in the DOM? Should I use a render function?

If you need a render function, I'll put it into a component and v-if it when needed. You could take this path too, but the first thing is to know if you even need a render function to begin with. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

@kissu the component I'm trying to render is a toast notification. I'd like it to render when I call a specific function.

I am not sure how this could be helpful for a toast notification, give a try to this rather. There is an example of a modal too, not too different from a toast. Render functions are not useful here for such a thing.

Use v-for (adapt to your needs):
Playground
<template>
  <button @click="generateItem()">Add item</button>
  <div class="container">
    <my-item v-for="item in items">{{ item }}</my-item>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { reactive } from 'vue'
  import MyItem from './MyItem.vue'
  const items = reactive([]);
  let counter = 1;
  function generateItem(){
    items.push('Item ' + counter++)
  }
</script>


I believe the render function is not meant to be used with <script setup>.
It is used as a flexible alternative to declare your render function programmatically, instead of using a template within a Vue SFC.
That said, you can achieve rendering a generated item like so:
<script setup>
  import { h, ref, shallowRef } from 'vue'
  import MyItem from './MyItem.vue'


  const component = shallowRef(null)
  function generateItem(){
    component.value = MyItem
  }
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="generateItem()">Add item</button>
  <div class="container">

    <component v-if="component" :is="component" :testStr="'The test str from App.vue'"></component>
  </div>
</template>

(see this playground url here: Vue SFC Playground)
This also works if you wrap with h(), but I believe it to be unnecessary:
component.value = h(MyItem)


Since MyItem will be used as a toast notification, I'll need to generate several. If I use  as a placeholder it will render all notifications in the same slot as opposed to stack new notifications on top of each other, right?

Depends on the styling of your Components, but you should be able to render them all and style accordingly using v-for and css.
